# how to make Instant Payment Forwarding

Tags: payment, php, javascript

so basicly im using block io API.
this is the respond:

```
{
  "status" : "success",
  "data" : {
    "network" : "BTC",
    "forwarding_private_key" : "L1xyqqzeM3V9mX2Cq75gudcD6HV7Vt6FfXzCEjQ5yKTH7wu43yhL",
    "forwarding_address" : "12eYNpH7chSAyTMcGCyq1rd93kURQSYHif",
    "to_address" : "16GyhGWV4xNEFRKLQ27CGY6epcRMg2mdWm"
  }
}
```

this is a JSON right,,??
now i want to show only forwarding_address to user using javascript or PHP.
can someone show me how to doit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **extracting substrings is by not a Cryptocurrency specific task, and should be easy to find on Stackoverflow**. See for example: [extracting data from json string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22628457/1364089).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to decode the JSON? Unless I'm missing something, that would just be `json_decode($response)['data']['forwarding_address']`